# Dynamic tensor shape for tensorflow RNN

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying a very simple example for tensorflow RNN. 
In that example, I use dynamic rnn. The code is as follows:

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10,1]) #Number of examples, number of input, dimension of each input
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 11])
num_hidden = 24
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden,state_is_tuple=True)
val, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)
val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2])
last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, int(target.get_shape()[1])]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[target.get_shape()[1]]))
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(prediction,1e-10,1.0)))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)
mistakes = tf.not_equal(tf.argmax(target, 1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))
```

Actually, the code is taken from this [tutorial](http://monik.in/a-noobs-guide-to-implementing-rnn-lstm-using-tensorflow/).
The input to this RNN network is a sequence of binary numbers. Each number is put into an array. For example, a seuquence has format: 
`[[1],[0],[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[1],[0]]`
The shape of the input is [None,10,1] which are batch size, sequence size and embedding size, respectively. Now because dynamic rnn can accept variable input shape, I change the code as follows:

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None,1])
```

Basically, I want to use variable-length sequences (of course same length for all sequences in the same batch, but different between batches). However, it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnn-lstm-variable-length.py", line 48, in <module>
    last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)
```

I understand that the second dimension is `None`, which cannot be used in `get_shape()[0]`. However, I believe that there must be a way to overcome this because RNN accepts variable lenth inputs, in general.
How can I do it?

Comment: Checkout this [blog](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/) post.

Comment: Are you sure that they're correct? They use `sequence = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, frame_size])`, which means sequence length is fixed.

Comment: For some reason I have the impression things aren't actually dynamic length, but padded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.gather` expects a tensor, so you can use `tf.shape(val)` to get a tensor, calculated at run-time, for the shape of `val` - e.g. `tf.gather(val, tf.shape(val)[0] - 1)`

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**: try using `tf.batch(..., dynamic_pad=True)` to batch your data.

---

@[chris_anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008194/chris-anderson)'s comment is correct. Ultimately your network needs a dense matrix of numbers to work with and there are a couple of strategies to convert variable length data into hyperrectangles:

1. Pad all batches to a fixed size (e.g. assume a maximum length of say 500 items per input and every item in every batch is padded to 500). There is nothing dynamic about this strategy.
2. Apply padding per-batch to the length of the longest item in the batch (dynamic padding).
3. Bucket your input based on length and apply padding per-batch. This is the same as #2, but with less overall padding.

There are [other strategies](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.training/splitting_sequence_inputs_into_minibatches_with_state_saving) that you could use too.

To do this batching, you use:

1. `tf.train.batch` - by default it does no padding, you need to implement it yourself.
2. `tf.train.batch(..., dynamic_pad=True)`
3. `tf.contrib.training.bucket_by_sequence_length`

I suspect you're also confused by the use of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`. It's important to note that the `dynamic` in `dynamic_rnn` refers to the way that TensorFlow unrolls the recurrent part of the network. in `tf.nn.rnn`, the recurrence is done statically in the graph (there is no internal loop, it's unrolled at graph construction time). In `dynamic_rnn` however, TensorFlow uses `tf.while_loop` to iterate inside the graph at run time. To use dynamic padding, you need to use dynamic unrolling, but it does not do it automatically.

Comment: My problem is different. Actually, every item in a batch has the same sequence length. However, that length is not known, and different across batches. Therefore, I cannot assign the shape of the placeholder of the input data. If I use [batch_size,None,None], later in `tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)`, it throws error `TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)`

Comment: Oh right, `tf.gather` expects a tensor anyway, so you can use `tf.shape(val)` to get a tensor, calculated at run-time, for the shape of `val` - e.g. `tf.gather(val, tf.shape(val)[0] - 1)`.

Comment: Correct, I tried and it just works. If you replace the answer by this comment, I'll accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: @lenhhoxung - done, I'll leave this here in case it helps anyone else.